# GROUP BY with additional filter

Tags: sql-server

```
disposition    uniqueid
ANSWERED       1497366029.125604
NO ANSWER      1497366029.125604
NO ANSWER      1497366029.125604
NO ANSWER      1497368123.126371
NO ANSWER      1497368123.126371
ANSWERED       1497368123.126371
NO ANSWER      1497369528.126781
NO ANSWER      1497369528.126781
NO ANSWER      1497369528.126781

SELECT disposition, uniqueid
FROM cdr
GROUP BY disposition,uniqueid
```

I only want to return grouped rows that are 'NO ANSWER', any uniqueid which has 1 or more non 'NO ANSWER' disposition should be ignored.

In this example i'm trying to return a single row

```
NO ANSWER      1497369528.126781
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way would be

```
SELECT MAX(disposition) AS disposition,
       uniqueid
FROM   cdr
GROUP  BY uniqueid
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN disposition = 'NO ANSWER' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = 0
```

You could also do

```
SELECT uniqueid
FROM   cdr
WHERE disposition = 'NO ANSWER'
EXCEPT
SELECT uniqueid
FROM   cdr
WHERE disposition IS NULL OR  disposition <> 'NO ANSWER'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way by using **'having'**:

```
select * 
from [cdr] 
Where disposition='NO ANSWER'
group by disposition,uniqueid
having count(uniqueid) <=1;
```